# Compare value to previous value after group by function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have grouped my data like this: 
df1 = df.groupby(['Store', 'Region', 'Item'])

```
STORE  REGION  
Store1 West  Item price result
               1  1.00     0
               2  2.00     0
               3  2.00     0
                  2.50     1
               4  1.00     0
                  1.00     0
                   .50     1
                  1.00     1
```

Basically I want to indicate whether there was a price change by a 1 and 0 if no price change. If there is only one price per item, then I want the 0 to be returned in those instances also.

I have tried this with the code below but this fails:

```
data_cleaned.groupby(['STORE', 'REGION', 'Item'])['price'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == x.change.shift(1) else 0})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` with `diff`. Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                   'price': [1, 2, 2, 2.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1]})

df = df.set_index('Item')

df['change'] = df.groupby(level=0)['price'].diff().abs().gt(0).astype(int)

print(df)

      price  change
Item               
1       1.0       0
2       2.0       0
3       2.0       0
3       2.5       1
4       1.0       0
4       1.0       0
4       0.5       1
4       1.0       1
```

Comment: what about the columns I had grouped by? i.e. store and region

Comment: @Hana, Amend your code accordingly. I've provide a full example. The `level` argument accepts a sequence: `level : int, level name, or sequence of such, default None`